# Issue in load balacing in Nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, load-balancing

below is my  nginx config file:

```
http {
   
    upstream all {
        server localhost:9091;
        server localhost:9092;
    }

    server {
         listen 9090;
         server_name localhost;
         location / {
              proxy_pass http://all/;
         }
    }

}

events { }
```

and **I have 2 springboot services at 9091 and 9092.** There code is same for both except different ports on which the services are working, but my when **I go localhost:9090 it doesn't redirect to localhost:9091 or localhost:9092.** Can someone please help me out?

I am running the nginx file through docker and it is starting correctly

Comment: Are the springboot applications running in the same container as nginx or different ones?

Answer (score 0):

The nginx container running on 9090 is trying to redirect into **itself** at localhost:9091 and 9092

Either you need nginx on your host, where I assume you're running the spring apps, or you need to containerize your spring app since nginx in a container can't redirect traffic to your host

If you really want to run multiple docker servers, I suggest simply using minikube/k3d instead with a k8s load balancer service